# It there a way to say 'early arrival' or ' arrive earlier than expected' in a single word?

Tags: word-choice

It there a way to say `early arrival` or `arrive earlier than expected` in a single word?

Comment: Early on its own might be sufficient.  Consider an early guest or an early train. The arrival is implied.

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] your post and add an example sentence showing how you'd expect to use the word. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the [Tour]. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> It there a way to say early arrival or arrive earlier than expected in
>   a single word?

[Premature](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/premature)

adjective

> - occurring, coming, or done too soon
>
> secondarily:  mature or ripe before the proper time.